# Can I make docker an environment without saving code

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, virtual-machine

I'm new to docker and I wonder that, can I use the docker as an application environment only?

I have the `Dockerfile` which let me build a Docker image and let other team-mates and server able to run my project.

```
FROM node:10.15.3
ADD . /app/
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
ENV HOST 0.0.0.0
ENV PORT 3000
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "run","start"]
```

The project can be built and ran. All the thing is perfect.

However, I found that all the files will be zip into the image files. My source code and all node_modules. It makes the files too big.

And I remember that in my previous project, I will create the Linux VM and bind my project folder to the guest OS. Then I can keep developing and using the vm as a server.

Can docker do something like this? The docker only needs to load my project folder (which will pass the path when running the command).

Then it runs `npm install`,  `npm start/dev`. All the library will save into my local directory. OR I run the `npm start` manually then the docker load my files and host.

I just need docker to be my application server to make sure I can get the same result like deployed to the Production server.

Can Docker do this?

============================== Update ================================

I try to use the bind mount to do this.
Then I create the docker-compose

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      -  type: bind
         source: C:\myNodeProject
         target: /src/
    ports:
      - '8888:3000'
```

and I update the dockerfile

```
FROM node:10.15.3

# Install dependencies
WORKDIR /src/


# I ran 'CMD ls' then confirm that the directory is blinded 

# Expose the app port
EXPOSE 3000

# Start the app
CMD  yarn dev
```

and I get the error

```
web_1  | yarn run v1.13.0
web_1  | $ cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon server/index.js --watch server
web_1  | [nodemon] 1.18.11
web_1  | [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
web_1  | [nodemon] watching: /src/server/**/*
web_1  | [nodemon] starting `node server/index.js`
web_1  | [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const consola = require('consola')
const { Nuxt, Builder } = require('nuxt')
const app = express()

// Import and Set Nuxt.js options
const config = require('../nuxt.config.js')
config.dev = !(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')

async function start() {
  // Init Nuxt.js
  const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)

  const { host, port } = nuxt.options.server

  // Build only in dev mode
  if (config.dev) {
    const builder = new Builder(nuxt)
    await builder.build()
  } else {
    await nuxt.ready()
  }

  // Give nuxt middleware to express
  app.use(nuxt.render)

  // Listen the server
  app.listen(port, host)
  consola.ready({
    message: `Server listening on http://${host}:${port}`,
    badge: true
  })
}
start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker can also work the way you've suggested using Volume Bind from Host OS it's useful in development while you can edit your codes and Docker container can immediately run that code.

However, in production, you don't want to follow the same practice.

Main principles of Docker containers is that an image is immutable
Once you built, it’s unchangeable, and if you want to make changes, you’ll need to build a new image as a result.

And for you're a concern that Docker can load all the necessary dependencies in production same as local them this thing managed by `package.lock.json` which will make sure whenever someone run `npm install` it'll install same dependencies.

For production mode, you're Docker Container needs to be lighted weighted so there'll be your code and `node_modules` and it's good practice to remove `npm` cache after installation to keep your Docker images size minimum as possible. Keeping size less give less space for security hole and fast deployment.

Comment: From the error, I can see there's something wrong in your `index.js`. Can you post your `index.js` file also to get a better insight?

Comment: This is the Nuxt.js + express project, I never change the default index.js.

Comment: Can you reinstall node_modules? Just ssh into a container and run `npm install` and the try to run `yarn dev`

Comment: Hello, I re- npm install and it is able to host the web now. Thanks.